# How to create auto scrolling in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, scroll

I want to create automatic scrolling of a page using Vue JS I looked at some options, but they did not help me here is my code

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.wrapper {
  width: min-content;
  margin: auto;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.main {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Here is the given [code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-sun-309or)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an interval that executes at your desired frequency and scrolls from the top based on some mathematical calculation.

```
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper')

setInterval( () => {
  wrapper.scrollTop = wrapper.scrollTop + 20
}, 1000)
```